# Python: crosstab plotted with plotly in a correct and easier way?

Tags: python, plotly

I have a working solution to create a frequency table form a pandas dataframe and plot it as a stacked bar plot:

```
ct = pd.crosstab(df['month'], df['region'])  # frequency table
ct.plot.bar(stacked=True) # create the bar plot of the frequencies
```

Now I would need exactly this in plotly. What I have is:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from matplotlib import cm

ct = pd.crosstab(df['month'], df['region'])  # frequency table

colorMap = cm.get_cmap('jet', numEl)
data = []
# e.g. ct.values 11x8
for idx, colName in enumerate(ct.columns):
    currColor = colorMap(idx/numEl)
    g = go.Bar(
        x=myX,
        y=ct.values[:, idx],
        name=colName,
        marker=dict(color=currColor)
    )

    data.append(g)

# plot the data for example as dcc.Graph (import dash_core_components as dcc)
```

The problem is that the colors are wrong and certainly there must be an easier solution than this wild hand-made code?

Answer (score 4):

I just recently did something like this for a Django app. I wanted the user to give two variables for a pandas data frame and have a cross tabulation with an associated stacked bar graph spit out. Here's how I did it and hopefully it helps simplify things a bit even though it's very similar:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
# Create data frame example
df = pd.DataFrame({'animal' : ['fish','fish','monkey'], 'zoo':['San Diego','Los Angeles','Santa Monica']})
#Cross-tabulate the example data frame.
df_cross = pd.crosstab(df.animal,df.zoo)
# initiate data list for figure
data = []
#use for loop on every zoo name to create bar data
for x in df_cross.columns:
   data.append(go.Bar(name=str(x), x=df_cross.index, y=df_cross[x]))

figure = go.Figure(data)
figure.update_layout(barmode = 'stack')

#For you to take a look at the result use
figure.show()

#Since I was using django I had to use plot from plotly.offline to send the html to the 
# form
figure_div = plot(figure,output_type='div')
```

I used the following as a reference when I did this:
https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/#stacked-bar-chart

Have a good one man!